# Autoincrement in SQLite tables

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment

I create a table, lets name it `CUSTOMERS` in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE "CUSTOMERS" (
    "tel" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    "customer" VARCHAR ,
);
```

When I see the table from a GUI (I use SQLite Manager from Firefox), I noticed that there is an extra column `rowid` which is working like auto-increment. My question is, in tables where I don't use a primary key should I specify a column like:

```
ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

If I execute this query `PRAGMA table_info(CUSTOMERS);` I get only the two columns `tel`,`customer`.

Comment: http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), as it was commented in your question.

However, if you are in a dilemma what to choose between these options, SQLite recommends that you should not use `AUTOINCREMENT` attribute because:

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

More info you can read [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/).

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite usually adds a `rowid` automatically as @laato linked in the comments [SqLite : ROWID](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

That can be removed, but does not need to be specified.   So there is no need to add it to the Create Table.

The hidden rowid allows delete's to be targetted at a single row, bu
t if you are using the `ROWID` as a specific foreign key, it would be better to name a column explicitly.  That will then become a synonym with the `rowid`.